# Is brewing coffee with milk instead of water a bad idea? And if so, how bad is it?

Tags: milk

I remember a Friday night kitchen experiment when I mixed very hot low-fat milk with coffee powder and partially ran it through a paper filter. Many of the complex, high-molecular milk components didn't make it through the filter, so they blocked the whole surface leading to only small volume of bright-brownish liquid in the container. But I also remember that the taste was extremely smooth and new to me. In another test, I would like to use a french press with milk instead of water... Does anyone here has experience with milk-brewed coffee?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Milk in place of water](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/3641). One answer describes an experiment of using milk in a French press.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. It shows me that others indeed have tried this as well.